# should RMSE compared to the magnitude of response variable?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference

My response variable has large magnitudes. The mean is 30000ish in the unit of dollars. Then I can only get the RMSE to ~3 which does not feel too bad to me given the magnitude of the response variable. However I read that RMSE > 1 is considered bad. I should also add that my $R^2$ is extremely good.

Comment: RMSE *per se* is usually meaningless *because it is expressed in the units of measure of the response variable.*  Thus, whenever you have a choice of the units to use, RMSE alone will not suffice.  The exceptions are (1) responses with intrinsic meaning, such as counts; and (2) RMSE of zero, implying the fit is exact.  Even in the context of a mean of 30000 an RMSE of 3 is not necessarily good (although it likely is for dollars). A common example would be surveying errors, where map coordinates could be in the millions of meters but centimeter-level accuracy is needed.

Comment: "I read that RMSE > 1 is considered bad." We do get that misconception a lot around here. I wonder where it comes from? Do you remember by any chance, OP?

Answer (score 8):

*Of course* you give context for RMSE. While RMSE does not have quite the same interpretation of mean absolute error (or median absolute error), if about half of your errors are within $3$ of gigantic values, that sounds pretty good for values around \$30,000. In other words, you are within about three bucks of the price of a car.

There is no rule about RMSE > 1 being bad. If you scale the $y$ to have a variance of $1$, then such a rule is more reasonable, but even then, it is hard to make an absolute measure of performance with qualitative descriptions like “good” and “bad” that apply in any circumstance without consideration of the context.